# in app purchase urban airship app in android

Tags: android, listview, urbanairship.com

Im about to make a android app and would like to use In-App-purchase in it. 
I have tried there sample code, and seems pretty easy, i just cant figure out how to use the data you buy (download) with in-app purchase.

The user have a listview with some text and a button, the text describe about the video he is going to download. When the user clicks the button in the list view i want the respective video to be downloaded from urban airship.

How to relate each list with the video in the server

Anyone have experience with this?

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to relate each list with the video
>   in the server

for in app billing you have to make product id on your android market account and the market will do the mapping between the product and its id which you will purchase through your application. In Android developer site it is very nicely explained....

see this link..
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html